# How to randomly place div inside parent with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a parent div (`fieldbox`) and a child div (`potbox`).

Inside the parent I want to place the child div with a **random** position on every page refresh.

For some reason, my solution does not work. I think the style is not defined. But I don't see why...

```js
const potboxRandom = document.querySelector('potbox')

const fieldWidth = 600;
const fieldHeight = 500;

randomTop = getRandomNumber(0, fieldWidth);
randomLeft = getRandomNumber(0, fieldHeight);

potboxRandom.style.top = `${randomTop}px`
potboxRandom.style.left = `${randomLeft}px`

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.fieldbox {
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  background: lightskyblue;
}

.potbox {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldbox">
  <div class="potbox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `potbox` is a class. So your `document.querySelector('potbox')` will be undefined. Instead add `document.querySelector('.potbox')`

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you randomSoul!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just a selector problem in `querySelector`, use `.potbox` instead of potbox

```js
const potboxRandom = document.querySelector('.potbox')

const fieldWidth = 600;
const fieldHeight = 500;

randomTop = getRandomNumber(0, fieldHeight - potboxRandom.clientHeight);
randomLeft = getRandomNumber(0, fieldWidth - potboxRandom.clientWidth);

potboxRandom.style.top = `${randomTop}px`
potboxRandom.style.left = `${randomLeft}px`

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.fieldbox {
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  background: lightskyblue;
}

.potbox {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldbox">
  <div class="potbox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works fine, but the child div is still not placed to the boundaries of the parent div. In some cases it is placed outside of the parent div.

Comment: It will remain inside the container now